# MySQL - How do I give users in SQL access to different files

Tags: php, mysql, user-permissions, file-access

I am a drumline instructor for a local high school and I am in the process of making a webpage for the students to access their music.

I am making a **user list** in a table and need to add **permissions** to the **users** so that they can only **access music** (PDF files) that I assign to them. Initially, I thought about maybe using an array for filenames, but after seeing how much controversy there is over arrays in SQL, I decided to reach out and see if there are better recommendations.

As of right now, I have a table with all of the users'
there columns are 
**emails,**

**passwords,**

**first/last names,**

and **instruments.**

I would like to be able to just add another field to this that controls what files they have access to.

Comment: Don't add a column, add a junction table (e.g. `student_music`) where you link users to files.

Comment: you can add a column of bit /boolean type to give access and set their value to true /false on permission

Comment: You can add a field to define usergroup, then give access of certain files only to the defined group

Comment: @smile regarding a junction table, would making another table with the filenames as individual rows then the users' emails that are allowed to access that file as columns be what you mean by that? In which case, loading the files would scan the columns after each song title for that user's name, right? If that's the case, would this be easier to do with XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship between students and files. The way we generally solve this in MySql is by creating a [pivot table](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/). Here is a small example:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE assignments (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    filepath VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_assignment (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    assignment_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id) REFERENCES assignments (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

So, each entry in the `user_assignment` pivot table signifies that the user with the id `user_id` has access to the assignment with the id `assignment_id`.